# Read an input line by line and convert to vector and print

Tags: c++, string, vector, printing, output

Trying to input exactly the following data containing `14` urls in `7` lines.

```
google.com gmail.com
google.com maps.com
facebook.com ufl.edu
ufl.edu google.com
ufl.edu gmail.com
maps.com facebook.com
gmail.com maps.com
```

via `cin` and store each URL as a vector and print just the unique vectors like this in `c++` :

```
1 google.com
2 gmail.com
3 facebook.com
4 maps.com
5 ufl.edu
```

So far I have done following code but it's not printing the `vector`.

```
int main()
{
  vector<string> Urls;
  std::string urls;
  std::getline(std::cin, urls); // get first line
  std::istringstream iss(urls);
  std::string word;

  while (std::getline(std::cin, urls)) {
      std::cout << urls << "\n";
      Urls.push_back(word);    
  }

  for(int i =0; i <Urls.size(); i++) {
     cout <<Urls[i]<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: How will you take input of the data. Is it provided in a file?

Comment: I just added my code so far. I'm taking the data using getline(cin) not a file

Comment: How many lines of data will be there?

Comment: just the 7 that I mentioned

Comment: And, is it fixed that each line will contain 2 urls ?

Comment: yes it is fixed at 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your constraint for input is always fixed. There are 7 lines of input and each line contains 2 urls. So, overall we have to scan for 14 urls as string. And, for finding unique strings, we can use `hashMap` to store urls and insert url into the vector only if it is not in `hashMap`. The overall code is:

```
int main() {
vector<string>uniqueUrl;
unordered_map<string,bool>hashMap;
for (int i = 0; i < 14; ++i) {
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    if (hashMap.find(s) == hashMap.end()) {
        uniqueUrl.push_back(s);
        hashMap[s] = true;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < uniqueUrl.size(); ++i) {
     cout<<uniqueUrl[i]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```